# Create custom list using json data in Blackberry 10 using QML

Tags: json, listview, qml, blackberry-10, momentics

I am getting JSON data from the web service below:

```
"List1": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title1",
            "picture":"myURL"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Title2",
            "picture":"myURL" 
        }
]
```

Now, I want to create a custom `ListView` using this JSON data, with the title and image.

I have tried many examples for this. Some of links are given below:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/JSONListModel
http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/using_data_source.html

But, I still cannot find any solutions. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a list is simple enough task. It's a bit harder because you want to show image from the internet, so you have to use a custom class for this. Download [WebImageView.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RileyGB/BlackBerry10-Samples/master/WebImageViewSample/src/WebImageView.cpp) and [WebImageView.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RileyGB/BlackBerry10-Samples/master/WebImageViewSample/src/WebImageView.h) and add them inside `/src` directory (if you want to take a look at the [whole project](https://github.com/RileyGB/BlackBerry10-Samples/tree/master/WebImageViewSample) or just follow my steps).

Add the following inside `applicationui.cpp` to include new class

```
#include "WebImageView.h"
```

and inside `ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app)` add

```
qmlRegisterType<WebImageView>("org.labsquare", 1, 0, "WebImageView");
```

so your QML can access this class.

This is a complete working sample of QML:

```
import bb.cascades 1.2
import bb.data 1.0
import org.labsquare 1.0

NavigationPane {
    id: nav
    Page {
        Container {
            ListView {
                dataModel: dataModel 
                listItemComponents: [
                    ListItemComponent {
                        type: "item"
                        content: Container {
                            Label {
                                text: ListItemData.title
                            }
                            WebImageView {
                                url: "http://adev.si/files/"+ListItemData.picture
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
                attachedObjects: [
                    GroupDataModel {
                        id: dataModel
                        grouping: ItemGrouping.None
                    },
                    DataSource {
                        id: dataSource
                        source: "http://adev.si/files/someData.json"
                        remote: true
                        onDataLoaded: {
                            dataModel.insertList(data.List1)
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        dataSource.load();
    }
}
```

I hope this helped. You also need this inside your .pro file

```
LIBS   += -lbbdata
QT += network
```

If you want to you [can import this project and use it](http://adev.si/files/soquestionproject.zip).

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. It works great. I really appreciate your help. But there is one thing which i want to know that how can i pass POST method instead of GET method in DataSource?? Because we use POST method in our project. So, please let me know ASAP.

Comment: I don't think Cascades has built in POST anywhere, so try and use `XMLHttpRequest()`, which is JavaScript function.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So, please can you give me any example if you have for the POST method using `XMLHttpRequest()`, also if you want i can provide you my URL which i am using... Thank you once again for your all kind of help.